# Blocking all traffic to one port except for a block of IPs

Tags: linux, firewall

I would just like to confirm that I am doing this right before I actually do it. 
I am trying to block all traffic to port 25 on a linux machine except for one block of IPs.
My last attempt blocked me from accessing the server completely so I figured I would ask before doing so again.  Here are my iptable rules, please let me know if this is correct.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 64.235.144.0/20 --destination-port 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 25 -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `INPUT` chain has no rules before your two rules and the `OUTPUT` chain doesn't block the response packets, this should work the way expected.

Maybe it is a good idea to insert another rule to the chain before *playing around*:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

`-I` adds it as first rule in the chain, so it takes precedence over others. This rule accepts all packets of already established connections. So even if you append other rules, you won't be locked out immediately from your SSH session. New connections won't be matched by this first rule.

If you use restrictive filtering for outgoing packets, you may add the same rule to the `OUTPUT` chain as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info, much appreciated.  So you are saying to put the rule you mentioned prior to all other rules in the chain?  And then I can add the two new rules I need after the existing?

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks for the great explanation and the safe guard to put in place!